# Unable to ping the vm running with ebpf program

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, ping, linux-kernel

I am using an eBPF program which counts the number of packets received on its interface on my destination vm.

At first I can able to ping the vm running with eBPF program that is destination from the source vm.

But after successfully compiling, loading into the kernel and attaching the eBPF program to interface, I was unable to ping destination vm.

I am getting the output in my source for `ping` command like `Destination host unreachable`.

I even used `sudo tcpdump icmp -i enp0s3 -en` command to capture the packets at the interface enp0s3 in destination, but didn't get any output.

I am using the virtual box for the above implementation.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of all involved networks: the host you ran the ping from, the guest VM, and the routing table on each.   Also, please include the source of your eBPF program.